# How to pass function by reference?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pass-by-reference, function-object

I have a C++ program that has free standing functions.

Since most of the team has little experience with or knowledge of object oriented design and programming, I need to refrain from function objects.

I want to pass a function to another function, such as `for_each` function.  Normally, I would use a function pointer as a parameter:

```
typedef void (*P_String_Processor)(const std::string& text);
void For_Each_String_In_Table(P_String_Processor p_string_function)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < table_size; ++i)
  {
    p_string_function(table[i].text);
  }
}
```

I want to remove pointers since they can point to anywhere, and contain an invalid content.

Is there a method to pass a function by reference, similar to passing by pointer, without using function object?

Example:

```
  // Declare a reference to a function taking a string as an argument.
  typedef void (??????);  

  void For_Each_String_In_Table(/* reference to function type */ string_function);
```

Comment: "...most of the team has little experience with or knowledge of object oriented design and programming..." - kind of revelation rarely seen among programmers in C++ :))

Comment: @SChepurin: Most of the team are C programmers.

Comment: another option would be skipping the typedef all together and using `template<typename T> void For_Each_String_In_Table( T& stringFunc )` but might lead to discussion between the 'generic' and 'it's not clear' camps

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - "Most of the team are C programmers." - never thought that for C programmers function objects are less OOP oriented than templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your function pointer type to a function reference (`*` -> `&`):

```
typedef void (&P_String_Processor)(const std::string& text);
```

Comment: Isn't the `&P_String_Processor` parsed as the address of the function?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nope. `&` has different meanings depending on the context. In a type, `&` means "reference". In an expression, `&` means "address of". In this case, it's certainly not an expression. It's part of the type.

Comment: Please include an example of calling the function reference.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Calling a reference to a function is exactly the same as calling a pointer to a function.

Comment: `typedef int (&a)(void);
  typedef int (*b)(void);
  a x = foo;
  b y = foo;
  b y1 = &foo;

  int res1 = x();
  int res2 = y();
  a z = *y;
  b zz = &x;`